# Bookmarks somehow?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Happens all the time I have something to say about a question I saw earlier, and I have a hard time finding it again. Is there a way to bookmark questions while browsing, so a guy can get back to them later?

Comment: well you have favorites but if your favorite list becomes long. it's not always easy to find them again.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work for the details of the feature.

Comment: I'd say hi, thanks. But suddenly I'm no longer qualified to even speak to you, measly 1043. heh...

Comment: I use the bookmark of the browser to remember a page to visit later. I only use the "favorite star" of SE when the question is truely interesting.

Comment: @David C.Ullrich: I am not sure to whom your comment was addressed. But you can use pings of the form `@username` to make sure that your comment will be seen by the user. If needed, you can find more detailed explanation how they work in the links given [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info) or in the post on meta tagged [meta-tag:comment-replies].

Comment: I am also a bit curious by your comment: *"I'm no longer qualified to even speak to you."* I do not know what you meant by that. But if you have problems using some features of the site, I suppose other users will be glad to help if you ask on meta, [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=math.stackexchange.com) or in comments to the post where you encountered the problem.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It was just a semi-private little joke, sorry. Some years ago a lot of the big shots here were part of the unofficial council of elders on sci.math, as was I. So back then I'd get some sort of grudging respect over there. Now I'm new here, all those guys got here years ago, so the rep system makes me officially just one of the village idiots. (No, not really - that's just what the joke was.)

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is plenty of people round hear who recognize your name from sci.math.

Comment: Yes. That's why it was a _joke_... sorry to waste your time on the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can favorite a question by clicking on the star under the voting arrows.

[image]

Then you can find them back in your profile under Activity -> favorite ([here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites)).

Comment: Well the rules say I shouldn't post a comment saying no more than "thanks", so I won't.